# Please help me with the answer of below questions regarding Apps packaging?

Tags: windows-installer

iam having a msi, files location was appdata\local with active setup. i am upgrading to new version with location Programfiles(x86).
-when i install new version alone files falling under Programfiles(x86).
-when i am having old version in machine and i try to install new version files are falling under appdata\local itself.

Q. What i need to do for files will fall under pgmfiles(x86)? is there any custom action, or any table modification let me know.

Tried to change location but files is installing umder appdata only not under program files .

Comment: check msi logs for INSTALLDIR property, this should show when and how its valus is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall the existing package from Programs and Feature, when you subsequently install the newer version, you should be prompted for the installation location. If that's not the case, then hopefully you should find reference to INSTALLDIR in the MSI log that gives you a clue as to where that value is being populated from (e.g. the registry), and you can modify it there.

If you want to do this as an automated step in an in-place upgrade, then you'll need to write custom code to (re)set INSTALLDIR after the ReadyToInstall action and the InstallValidate action.